# Close session and all buffers with one command

Tags: sessions

I often use sessions to edit and track files in a project. I almost always type `:q` when I'm done working and end up closing the buffer I was last working on when what I want to do is close all buffers and quit vim.

Is there a native way to close all buffers of a session with a single command rather than just the active buffer?

Comment: Q: "Is there a variant of <thing> that works a bit differently?" A: `:help <thing>` and scroll around."

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
:qa
```

for quit all or

```
:qa!
```

The later forces to quit Vim even if some buffer modifications have nor been saved.